# How to find the location of a column in multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr, sqldf

I have many data frames that are kind of similar to the 4 data frames that have created below:-

```
red<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,5),d=c(1,2,3))
blue<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),d=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,5))
green<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,5),d=c(1,2,3))
pink<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),d=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,5))
```

The output that I want would look like the following

```
Location  |Freq/Count|Colnames

    1     |     4    |    A

    2     |     2    |    B

    3     |     2    |    B

    2     |     2    |    D

    3     |     2    |    D
```

The above output shows that in all 4 data frames A is the label of first column while B is the label of 2 columns only in 2 data frames.

I want generate this output in R for many files with the same columns. I want to Know the positions of each column in many files in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness and as the question was tagged accordingly, here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(lapply(list(red, blue, green, pink), names), value.name = "Colnames"))[
  , Location := rowid(L1)][, .N, keyby = .(Colnames, Location)]
```

> ```
>    Colnames Location N
> 1:        a        1 4
> 2:        b        2 2
> 3:        b        3 2
> 4:        d        2 2
> 5:        d        3 2
> ```

It uses `melt()` to reshape the list with the column names returned by the call to `lapply()` to a data.frame in long format. After coersion to data.table, the locations are appended using the `rowid()` function. Finally, the number of occurrences by `Colnames` and `Location` are computed.

Note that this works also for a list of data.frames with differing number of columns.

The `data.table` package includes an optimized method of `melt()` for `data.table` objects. For `data.frame`, `array`, and `list` objects the respective methods from the `reshape2` package are dispatched.

The `value.name` parameter specifies the name for the molten data values column. The default name `value` is replaced by `Colnames` as requested by the OP. Please, see the help page `?melt` for more details.

Comment: What is value.name for and  what does it do?

Comment: @sidsatam, I have added more explanations as requested.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this hacky solution:

```
foo <- do.call(rbind, 
               lapply(list(red, pink, blue, green), names))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  "d" 
# [2,] "a"  "d"  "b" 
# [3,] "a"  "d"  "b" 
# [4,] "a"  "b"  "d" 

result <- reshape2::melt(apply(foo, 2, table))
# Var1 value L1
#   a     4  1
#   b     2  2
#   d     2  2
#   b     2  3
#   d     2  3

# To get wanted result 
colnames(result) <- c("Colnames", "Freq", "Location")
result[order(result$Colnames), c("Location", "Freq", "Colnames")]
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without rbind?

Comment: I don't want rbind because all files that I have don't have same number of columns. And sapply is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: Shouldn't the code be foolproof @PoGibas irrespective of what I give.

Answer (score 2):

Not using rbind:

```
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(x) {
  tibble(Colnames = names(x), Location = seq(Colnames))
}

list(red, blue, green, pink) %>%
  map_df(f) %>%
  group_by(Location, Colnames) %>%
  summarize(Freq = n()) %>%
  arrange(Location, Freq)
```

Output:

```
A tibble: 5 x 3
Groups:   Location [3]
  Location Colnames  Freq
     <int>    <chr> <int>
1        1        a     4
2        2        b     2
3        2        d     2
4        3        b     2
5        3        d     2
```

Comment: tidyr is part of the the tidyverse package system. This particular solution mainly uses purrr and dplyr functions, though.